# After installation of scikit-learn can't import sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip

I am trying to start with local machine learning and I am following this article https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-python-step-by-step/ and can't import sklearn.

On my Windows 10:

```
G:\Software\ML>pip list
Package         Version
--------------- ----------
cycler          0.10.0
joblib          0.13.2
kiwisolver      1.1.0
matplotlib      3.1.1
numpy           1.16.4+mkl
pandas          0.25.0rc0
pip             19.1.1
pyparsing       2.4.0
python-dateutil 2.8.0
pytz            2019.1
scikit-learn    0.21.2
scipy           1.3.0
setuptools      40.8.0
six             1.12.0

G:\Software\ML>python
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\akarasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
from .base import clone
File "C:\Users\akarasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 16, in <module>
from .utils import _IS_32BIT
File "C:\Users\akarasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
from . import _joblib
File "C:\Users\akarasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_joblib.py", line 8, in <module>
import joblib
File "C:\Users\akarasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
from .parallel import Parallel
File "C:\Users\akarasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 28, in <module>
from ._parallel_backends import (FallbackToBackend, MultiprocessingBackend,
File "C:\Users\akarasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 22, in <module>
from .executor import get_memmapping_executor
File "C:\Users\akarasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\executor.py", line 14, in <module>
from .externals.loky.reusable_executor import get_reusable_executor
File "C:\Users\akarasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from .backend.reduction import set_loky_pickler
File "C:\Users\akarasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\reduction.py", line 125, in <module>
from joblib.externals import cloudpickle  # noqa: F401
File "C:\Users\akarasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .cloudpickle import *
File "C:\Users\akarasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 152, in <module>
_cell_set_template_code = _make_cell_set_template_code()
File "C:\Users\akarasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 133, in _make_cell_set_template_code
return types.CodeType(
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
>>>
```

Any help appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you install the package?

Comment: @Alex_P `scikit-learn    0.21.2` not enough?

Answer (score -1):

Try to install the updated sklearn with:

`pip install -U scikit-learn`

Comment: Just tried again:   `C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install -U scikit-learn` and received `Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.11.0`, `Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: joblib>=0.11 `, `Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scipy>=0.17.0`